# Editing Existing Struct Type for API Calls

Tags: go, post, struct

I am working with an api endpoint and sending POST requests. Its a feed-like API that requires to start with a timestamp field to get an initial response, then use a provided ID (from the initial response) with which will be used as params for the next request. The timestamp is required in the initial request (but cannot provide an Id in the params) and future requests after the initial need to have no timestamp field but send params with the Id field only.

Essentially I am taking this first query set of params for first query

```
type Query struct {
    ApiKey string `json:"apiKey"`
    Params Params `json:"params"`
}

type Params struct {
    Timestamp string `json:"timestamp"` // needed for initial request
}
```

Then amending it for the second and subsequent requests like:

```
type Query struct {
    ApiKey string `json:"apiKey"`
    Params Params `json:"params"`
}

type Params struct {
    Id string `json:"id"` // populated with data from initial payload
}
```

However, I am curious if there is a better approach than having two separate structs (one for the initial params, and one for future params). It might be totally harmless to just use two structs for varied `Params`, I was just curious if there is a better approach since if I have an empty struct field, it will still be sent in `Params` with its zero value.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "bytes"
)

type Query struct {
    ApiKey string
    Params Params `json:"params"`
}

type Params struct {
    Timestamp string // needed for initial request
    Id        string // populated with data from initial response payload
}

func main() {

    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 30,
    }

    qry := Query{
        ApiKey: a,
        Params: Params{
            Timestamp: ts,
        },
    }
    
    // serialize query for POST
    data, _ := json.Marshal(qry)
    
    // construct first request
    req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, url, bytes.NewBuffer(data))

    // do request
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)

    // make next request with altered query 
    qry = Query{
        ApiKey: a,
        Params: Params{
            Id: id,
        },
    }

    // serialize query for POST
    data, _ := json.Marshal(qry)
    
    // construct first request
    req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, url, bytes.NewBuffer(data))

    // do request
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)
    

}
```

Comment: Use the single `Params` struct and add the `,omitempty` option to the struct tags, e.g. `Id string \`json:"id,omitempty"\``. The `,omitempty` option will "tell" the json marshaler to omit the field from the output if its value is empty.

Comment: Or if it's only for marshaling, make `Query.Params` an `interface{}` and fill it with whatever type is appropriate for the request. It just won't work cleanly for unmarshaling.